# Bind Config section to DataTable using c#

Tags: c#

I have the following config section in my app.config file and the code to iterate through config section to retrieve the values. But i want to save the values of config section to a datatable in a proper structure. How ? I want to show all the values in datagridview with appropriate columns.

```
  <configSections>
    <section name="ServerInfo" type="System.Configuration.IConfigurationSectionHandler" />
  </configSections>

  <ServerInfo>
    <Server id="1">
      <Name>SRUAV1</Name>
      <key> 1 </key>
      <IP>10.1.150.110</IP>
      <Port>7901</Port> 
    </Server>
    <Server id="2">
      <Name>SRUAV2</Name>
      <key> 4 </key>
      <IP>10.1.150.110</IP>
      <Port>7902</Port>
    </Server>
    <Server id="3">
      <Name>SRUAV3</Name>
      <key> 6 </key>
      <IP>10.1.150.110</IP>
      <Port>7904</Port>
    </Server>
  </ServerInfo>
```

Code :

```
public void GetServerValues(string strSelectedServer)
    {
        Configuration config = ConfigurationManager.OpenExeConfiguration(ConfigurationUserLevel.None); 
        ConfigurationSection section = config.GetSection("ServerInfo"); 
        XmlDocument xml = new XmlDocument();
        xml.LoadXml(section.SectionInformation.GetRawXml());
        string temp = "";
        XmlNodeList applicationList = xml.DocumentElement.SelectNodes("Server"); 
        for (int i = 0; i < applicationList.Count; i++)
        {
            object objAppId = applicationList[i].Attributes["id"];
            int iAppId = 0;
            if (objAppId != null)
            {
                iAppId = Convert.ToInt32(applicationList[i].Attributes["id"].Value);
            } 
            temp = BuildServerValues(applicationList[i]);
        } 
    }

    public string BuildServerValues(XmlNode applicationNode)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < applicationNode.ChildNodes.Count; i++)
        {
            if (applicationNode.ChildNodes.Item(i).Name.ToString().Equals("Name"))
            {
                strServerName = applicationNode.ChildNodes.Item(i).InnerXml.ToString();
            }
            if (applicationNode.ChildNodes.Item(i).Name.ToString().Equals("IP"))
            {
                strIP = applicationNode.ChildNodes.Item(i).InnerXml.ToString(); 
            }
            if (applicationNode.ChildNodes.Item(i).Name.ToString().Equals("Port"))
            {
                strPort = applicationNode.ChildNodes.Item(i).InnerXml.ToString(); 
            }
        }
        return strServerName;
    }
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I prefer to use the existing configuration classes to build a strongly typed configuration section.  Firstly, I'd start with the server element itself:

```
public class ServerConfigurationElement : ConfigurationElement
{
  [ConfigurationProperty("id")]
  public int Id {
    get { return (int)this["id"]; }
    set { this["id"] = value; }
  }

  [ConfigurationProperty("name")]
  public string Name { 
    get { return (string)this["name"]; }
    set { this["name"] = value; }
  }

  [ConfigurationProperty("key")]
  public int Key {
    get { return (int)this["key"]; }
    set { this["key"] = value;
  }

  [ConfigurationProperty("ip")]
  public string IPAddress {
    get { return (string)this["ip"]; }
    set { this["ip"] = value; }
  }

  [ConfigurationProperty("port")]
  public int Port {
    get { return (int)this["port"]; }
    set { this["port"] = value; }
  }
}
```

This specifies a model for a singular configuration of a server.  We then need to create a collection class

```
[ConfigurationCollection(typeof(ServerConfigurationElement), AddItemName = "server")]
public class ServerConfigurationElementCollection : ConfigurationElementCollection
{
  protected override CreateNewElement() {
    return new ServerConfigurationElement();
  }

  protected override object GetElementKey(ConfigurationElement element) {
    return ((ServerConfigurationElement)element).Id;
  }
}
```

This allows the configuration system to create a collection of server configuration items. Lastly, we create a section:

```
public class ServerConfigurationSection : ConfigurationSection
{
  [ConfigurationProperty("servers")]
  public ServerConfigurationElementCollection Servers {
    get { return (ServerConfigurationElementCollection)this["servers"]; }
    set { this["servers"] = value; }
  }

  public static ServerConfigurationSection GetConfiguration() {
    return ConfigurationManager.GetSection("ServerInfo") as ServerConfigurationSection;
  }
}
```

The markup is slightly different from yours:

```
<configSections>
  <section name="ServerInfo" type="ServerConfigurationSection, MyAssembly" />
</configSections>

<ServerInfo>
  <servers>
    <server id="1" name="SRUAV1" ip="10.1.150.110" port="7901" />
  </servers>
</ServerInfo>
```

We can then use it in code:

```
/// <summary>
/// Binds the server configurations to the specified grid view.
/// </summary>
public void BindConfiguration(DataGridView gridView) {
  if (gridView == null)
    throw new ArgumentNullException("gridView");

  var config = ServerConfigurationSection.GetConfiguration();
  if (config != null) {
    gridView.DataSource = config.Servers.Cast<ServerConfigurationElement>().ToList();
  }
}
```

What I've done is I've pulled out the current configuration, and bound the elements to the datagrid via a List.

Hope that helps.